# Swift/tvOS: Complex Arrays with multiple strings?

Tags: arrays, swift, avplayer, tvos

**had to edit this because I wrote it in a confused way.**

I'm looking to create an Array, where each entry can be used to replace a function's parameters like this:

```
  func playMe(inputfile: String, inputtype: String)
```

with

```
  playMe(videoArray[0])
```

and that would then replace

```
  inputfile: String, inputtype: String
```

with

```
  inputfile: "file", inputtype: "mp4"
```

How would I go about creating it? I've tried

```
   var videoArray = [""Nameofvideo", inputtype: "mp4"", ""Nameofvideo2", inputtype: "mp4""]
```

but it simply does not want to work. What am I missing? Am I trying to do this in a too complex fashion? I was hoping to emerge with

```
   playMe(videoArray[1])
```

and then follow it with audioArray[1]  for the followup mp3. Hmm?

Here is my playMe code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "itemDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func playMe(inputfile: String, inputtype: String) {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(inputfile, ofType:inputtype)!
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: videoURL)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }

    func itemDidFinishPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
        playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
```

Comment: also considering the limited number of types you might want to create an enumeration with the player accepted types

Comment: You should also post your method playMe code

Comment: @LeoDabus Added playMe code and the required notifiers to return back to menu after playback stops.

Comment: you are declaring your AVPlayer inside viewDidLoad method so it will go out of existence almost immediately. You have to declare the player out of that method, inside your view controller class

Comment: @LeoDabus I understand it looks like that to you, but the viewDidLoad is actually shut - hence the last two characters of viewDidLoad are )}

Comment: try to keep your code as readable as possible. Close your brackets the next line as the Swift convention

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
var videoArray2 = [
    ["name": "Nameofvideo", "inputType": "mp4"],
    ["name": "Nameofvideo1", "inputType": "mp4"],
    ["name": "Nameofvideo2", "inputType": "mp4"]
]
```

or better:

```
struct Video {
    let name: String
    let inputType: String
}

var videoArray = [
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo", inputType: "mp4"),
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo2", inputType: "mp4"),
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo3", inputType: "mp4"),
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo4", inputType: "mp4")
]
```

if you can, consider using an enum type for `inputType`. like this:

```
enum InputType: String {
    case MP4 = "mp4"
    case MP3 = "mp3"
    case MKV = "mkv"
}

struct Video {
    let name: String
    let inputType: InputType
}

var videoArray = [
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo",  inputType: .MP4),
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo2", inputType: .MP4),
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo3", inputType: .MP4),
    Video(name: "Nameofvideo4", inputType: .MKV)
]
```

to call `playMe:inputtype:` write this:

```
let video = videoArray[1]
playMe(video.name, inputtype: video.inputType.rawValue) {
```

or update your `playMe` method to:

```
func playMe(video: Video) {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(video.name, ofType: video.inputType.rawValue)!
    ...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
self.playMe(videoArray[1])
```

Comment: Very good. But `VideoObject` should be renamed as `Video` since a `Struct` is not an object ;) Anyway you have my upvote.

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal: Another refinement: the properties in `Video` should be declared as `let`. Infact, IMHO, they are not supposed to change.

Comment: @appzYourLife I almost mentioned that

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal make your enum InputType: String and give them a string value "mp4"

Comment: @appzYourLife: but this works: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6tanip3umklbxv/Screenshot%202016-01-01%2021.42.41.png?dl=0 ?
appzYourLife: but this works: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6tanip3umklbxv/Screenshot%202016-01-01%2021.42.41.png?dl=0 ? 
LeoDabus: updated, thanks :)

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal: yes. However in Swift (like in others *Functional Programming* oriented languages) [immutability is often used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207757/why-do-immutable-objects-enable-functional-programming) to prevent coding errors. About your code, once you created a `Video` value you should not be able to change the `name` property. You should create a new `Video` value instead. This is a first step through the Functional Programming paradigm :)

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal Thing is, I'm running this inside a Playground to figure out which question I should go with, and trying to write Video[1] or videoArray[1]  does not output "name: "Nameofvideo2", inputType: "mp4") (I'm using the second one, the struct+var one). Since the output of this array would be used to call a function, I'm not sure how to proceed. Is Playground not equipped to handle structures and enumerations and variables of this complexity?  (Clarification: Xcode Playground because I tried to put it into the xcodeproject already and emerged with broken code)

Comment: @esaruoho i've updated your playMe: method in my post. it also works in playground :)

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal Hi, I wound up using a mixture of you and Anupam's suggestions, and now I'm not sure which one to set as the solution to the answer. I also don't think it's good of me to post an answer that uses both yours and Anupam's answers. Is the answer supposed to be the one that has all the answers altogether, or the one that wound up in the resultant functioning source code?

Answer (score 2):

To add [Devran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494219/devran-cosmo-uenal)'s answer, here is what you can do

```
enum MediaType: String {

    case mp4
    case mp3

    var description: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}

struct Media {

    var title: String
    var type: MediaType
}

let medias = [
    Media(title: "Game Of Thrones", type: .mp4),
    Media(title: "Harry Potter", type: .mp4),
    Media(title: "Coldplay Clocks", type: .mp3),
    Media(title: "In the End", type: .mp3),
]


func playMedia(media: Media) {

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(media.title, ofType: media.type.description) {
        // play media at path
    }
}
```

Comment: But `Media` and `MediaType` are way better names :)

Comment: Thanks @DevranCosmoUenal

Comment: I would just change  var mediaType: MediaType to  var type: MediaType

Comment: besides naming you should use URLForResource(withExtension:) to get the fileURL instead of the filePath

Comment: I would also just add a description property to the enumeration     `var description: String { return rawValue }`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus for suggestions. I have adhered some of the suggestion and removed the playMedia code as this might not be relevant for the quesion.

Comment: @Anupam Thanks for your multiple-edited answer!! However, question, I've tried to run this on a Playground to make more sense of it - since actually all the answers to this question are taking my mind out for a spin. I tried to do print (media.type) or Media.type or Media[1] or anything but can't grok it. How am I supposed to use this enum struct let thing to get the result that playMe (which I added to the original question) will want to work with it?

Comment: Though Devran's answer has the complete set of setup information, this answer provides the necessary change in the function's signature to accommodate the new input type. I think the most correct answer would be a fusion of both answers

Comment: @esaruoho, if I understand your doubt clearly, here is how you can access title from media structure instance "let title: String = media.title" and to access type use "let type: String = media.type.description"

Comment: @NewAlexandria Yeah, I agree with you. The only thing missing is how the calling of func playMe() should be altered to conform to Anupam's answer, with an example. Can you amend your answer, Anupam?

I'm guessing the answer is:
playMe(media[1]).

Comment: Correct !  this would even better -- "if let media = media[1] { playMedia(media)}". Simply calling "media[1]" may be nil.

Comment: @Anupam Hi, I wound up using a mixture of you and Devran's suggestions, and now I'm not sure which one to set as the solution to the answer. I also don't think it's good of me to post an answer that uses Devran's and Anupam's answers. Is the answer supposed to be the one that has all the answers altogether, or the one that wound up in the resultant functioning source code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of tuples to feed parameters as long as you match your function's call signature exactly:

```
let arrayOfMedia = 
[ 
 ( "Game Of Thrones", inputtype: ".mp4"),
 ( "Harry Potter",    inputtype: ".mp4"),
 ( "Coldplay Clocks", inputtype: ".mp3"),
 ( "In the End",      inputtype: ".mp3")     
]

playMe(arrayOfMedia[0])
```

if you want to be explicit for the first parameter name in your array of tuples, you need to change your function's signature to :

func playMe(inputfile inputfile: String, inputtype: String)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of dictionaries:

```
 var videoArray = [["videoName":"Nameofvideo", "inputtype": "mp4"], ["videoName":"Nameofvideo2", "inputtype": "mp4"]]
```

eventually, instead of repeating "videoName" and "inputtype", you could define two constants like:

```
static  let VideoName = "videoName"
static  let InputType = "inputtype"
```

and use them to define and access values contained within dictionaries.