# How to modify input value correctly and modify array value at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I render the values that I have inside an object and an input next to each of them with that object index item as value. When I try to use the onChange prop, I cannot modify neither the rendered value nor the input value. How can I do this changing the state of the element in the array?

**I want the Toto value to be modified as I change the input value**

[image: I want the Toto value to be modified as I change the input value]

**My object players looks like this:**

```
[
  {
  "name": "Toto";
  },
  {
   "name": "Lolz",
  }
]
```

**Here, I try to render my table:**

```
modifyItem = (event, index) => {
   this.state.players[index].name = event.target.value
   //my problem is clearly here
}

render() {
    const playersList = [...new Array(this.state.players.length)].map((it, index) => {
    return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{this.state.players[index].name}</td>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.players[index].name} onChange={this.modifyItem}/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    )
    })

    return () {
      <div>
         {playersList}
      </div>
    }
```

**What I want to do is:**

In each element of the table AND input ( for example the first one Toto), I want to modify this value in the input and consecutively in the table. I can't seem to find the correct answer.

Comment: The array is not empty because the value is rendered (notice the picture link). I'm not posting the entire code

Comment: I missed the `[...]` part. But that's a **hugely** convoluted way to just do `this.state.players.map()`: https://pastebin.com/f1uMbtaK

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You've said you want to 'change" something, but you've shown us a `render` function. You don't change things in `render`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Alright thanks for the tip. Do you know how would I be able to change the tables value (the element of my state object players[index].name) that is being modified in my input?

Comment: Please post the whole code if you want help. Also, I suggest learning and using Formik when doing forms in React. Specifically, its FieldArray (https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray) component in your case. It'll save you a lot of hassle compared to vanilla React in the end.

Comment: So, I would like to edit my array element's state with the help of ``event.target.value`` like I'm trying to set it directly (I know I should not). Which will make my Toto change to whatever the input's value is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a codesandbox example for you here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vnkoxop6z3

You need to store your values in state, and when you modify each item you need to know what the new value is via the onChange callback, and the index of that current value.

From here you can duplicate the array by spreading it into a new one, access that particular index item on the new array, and update the name with the new value.

Once you have done this. setState with the new array.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      values: [
        {
          name: "Toto"
        },
        {
          name: "Lolz"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  modifyItem(e, index) {
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    const values = [...this.state.values];
    values[index].name = newValue;

    this.setState({
      values
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.values.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <label>{value.name}</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={value.name}
            onChange={e => this.modifyItem(e, index)}
          />
        </Fragment>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.  What exactly does the ``[...this.state.values]`` mean?

Comment: No problem. It expands out iterable items. You can read more about it here on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

I used it in this instance to create a duplicate array before modifying it. Its a preferred method instead of modying existing data you should create a duplicate of it first.

Here is an answer on immutability https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207757/why-do-immutable-objects-enable-functional-programming